# App crashes while using UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have an app with two UIPickerViews that can appear within a UITableViewCell: numberPicker and timePicker. They never appear on screen at the same time, and they're declared like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!
```

Depending on which one is being used, the delegate and datasource are being set in awakeFromNib:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if timePicker != nil {
        timePicker.delegate = self
        timePicker.dataSource = self
    }

    if numberPicker != nil {
        numberPicker.delegate = self
        numberPicker.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

If numberPicker is the picker I'm trying to show, the app runs without a problem. If timePicker is the picker I'm trying to show, the app crashes. After setting breakpoints, this is the line it crashes on:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    if pickerView == numberPicker {  <----- CRASHES HERE ----->
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, the code works when numberPicker is trying to appear on the screen, and crashes when timePicker is trying to appear. Why is this occurring? Thanks in advance for the assistance!

**UPDATE**
Here is a screenshot of the error

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

My apologies for not including this sooner. My log window was minimized and I overlooked it and did not notice. The error is:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: In your delegate/datarouce your returning 2 components to the timePicker but are you actually supplying 2 components ? More code would help

Comment: can u show the crash report

Comment: @SeanLintern88  what more code would you like? that's pretty much all there is except for the remaining uipickerview delegate methods. I'll most likely have to refactor them as well because I use a similar if-statement in all of them, but this is the first line that crashes so it seems rather inconsequential to include them.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes let me get a screen shot of the crash report for you

Comment: you need to copy paste the log not screenshot the crash please

Comment: my mistake, sorry...coming right up. thanks for your patience

Comment: Sounds like a nil optional

Comment: yes it is a nil optional

Comment: are u removing the numPicker when timePicker is loading?

Comment: yes, numPicker and timePicker never appear in the cell at the same time.

Comment: I attempted using a switch statement and the same error occurs. Thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: rather than removing , try it with hidden property, I think it will be solved.

Comment: hidden didn't work unfortunately :/...I think i'm just going to end up creating two separate cells instead. One for each of the pickers